# Jenkins doesnot publish HTML report for a webdriverio automation suite

Tags: javascript, jenkins, webdriver-io, allure

[image]
I have set the HTML report path
[image]
HTML report is not getting published.

Any pointers why the report is not being published

Comment: There is not enough information in your question.  Have you checked the logs? what do the logs say?

Answer (score 0):

HTML Directory to archive should be as mentioned below:

```
**${workspace}\reports\html-reports**
```